# Mac M1 Attempted import error: 'Switch' is not exported from 'react-router'

Tags: reactjs, react-router

On Windows, `npm run start` works fine, but `npm run start` on m1 gives an error.
 Why are you doing this?

```
Failed to compile
./node_modules/react-router-config/esm/react-router-config.js
Attempted import error: 'Switch' is not exported from 'react-router'.
This error occurred during the build time and cannot be dismissed.
```

`"react-router-dom": "^5.3.0", "react-scripts": "^4.0.1",`

This is the app.js code.

```
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import routes from "./Routes";
import {renderRoutes} from "react-router-config";


import theme from './theme';
import {ThemeProvider} from "styled-components";

export default function App() {
    return (
                    <BrowserRouter>
                        {renderRoutes(routes)}
                    </BrowserRouter>
    );
};
``
```

Comment: `Switch` has been replaced by `routes` if you're using react-router v6. So check that.

Answer (score 1):

If you accidentally updated `react-router-dom` to version 6 it no longer exports a `Switch` component. It was replaced by a `Routes` component that ***must*** directly wrap/render the `Route` components.

1. Swap the `Switch` for the `Routes` component.

   ```
   import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
   ...

   function App() {
     return (
       <Router>
         <Routes>
           <Route path="/" element={<Home/>} />
         </Routes>
       </Router>
     );
   }
   ```

   Follow the [Upgrading from v5](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/upgrading/v5) to migrate your project from v5 to v6 across your app as there were quite a few breaking component API changes.
2. Revert back to `react-router-dom` v5.

   - Run `npm un -s react-router-dom`
   - Run `npm i -s react-router-dom@5.3.0`

Comment: I have a part that needs to be updated right away, do I really need to migrate? Will there be errors even with the old version?

Comment: @skksks I'd revert back to v5 until ready to upgrade, especially if there's non-trivial work to do so.

Comment: `react-router-dom` is version 5, but I keep getting `switch` errors.

Comment: If you were running RRDv5 then it should certainly export a `Switch` component. From your project directory run `npm list react-router-dom` to see what the installed version actually is. If you are on v5 then make sure you've stopped/killed any code watchers/hot-reloaders and restarted your development server.

Comment: Looks like you've two versions installed? Are you running in a mono-repo? Whichever one is on v6 should be rolled back to v5 to match all usages across your app.

Comment: I tried `npm uninstall react-router-dom`, `npm uninstall react-router-dom@6.0.2` but version 6 is not uninstalled.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be that of the version of `react-router-dom` The code that you have written seems to be compatible with `version 5` and the package that you have installed is likely `version 6`. Please check.

In `version 6`

1. `Switch` is replaced with `Routes`
2. Default behavior of routes is to match exact routes.
3. `component={Loader}` must now be written as `element={<Loader />}`
4. `useHistory` is replaced with `useNavigate`.
5. The order in which we list the routes does not matter. the algorithm now selects the best possible match.

### Steps to upgrade to v6

```sh
npm uninstall react-router-dom
```

```sh
npm install react-router-dom@6
```

Then follow the below-mentioned tutorial to make the changes in your code. It should start working fine.

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";

function App() {
  return (
    <Router basename={process.env.PUBLIC_URL}>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Home/>} />
        <Route path="/dashboard" element={<Dashboard/>} />
        <Route path="/*" element={<NotFoundPage/>} />
      </Routes>
    </Router>
  );
}
```

Also, it is a good practice to make use of `basename={process.env.PUBLIC_URL}` to set the public url through `.env` file.

### The other way to solve this

The other way would be to revert back to version 5 but I would highly encourage you to upgrade to version 6 since it offers a smaller bundle size, better route selection, improved coding style and a lot more intuitive way of coding the nested routes.

### References

1. [Upgrading to v6 Guide](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/upgrading/v5)
2. [Upgrading to v6 Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zEQiNFAwDGo&t=1s&ab_channel=Academind)

Comment: I have a part that needs to be updated right away, do I really need to migrate? Will there be errors even with the old version?

Comment: The old version is buggy. Especially when handling 404 routes. I have had cases where two components are being rendered for upgrading to version 6 hardly takes 30 minutes. I would say it's worth the time as it improves the performance overall.