# How to convert all "Route" including "AdminRoute" to latest "react-router-dom"?

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

**Here's how I can convert "AdminRoute" to the latest "react-router-dom"...**

```
<Switch>
          <Route exact="exact" path={path}>
              <DashboardHome></DashboardHome>
          </Route>
          <AdminRoute path={`${path}/addProduct`}>
              <AddProduct></AddProduct>
          </AdminRoute>
          <AdminRoute path={`${path}/manageProducts`}>
              <ManageProducts></ManageProducts>
          </AdminRoute>
          <AdminRoute path={`${path}/makeAdmin`}>
              <MakeAdmin></MakeAdmin>
          </AdminRoute>
    </Switch>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mac M1 Attempted import error: 'Switch' is not exported from 'react-router'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70271581/mac-m1-attempted-import-error-switch-is-not-exported-from-react-router) or [./src/App.js Attempted import error: 'Switch' is not exported from 'react-router-dom'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70266560/src-app-js-attempted-import-error-switch-is-not-exported-from-react-router/70266648#70266648)

Answer (score 0):

You don't have wrap inside Switch instead use Routes, check [here](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/getting-started/overview#configuring-routes)

```
  <BrowserRouter>
    <Routes>
      <Route path={path} element={<DashboardHome />}>
      ...
    </Routes>
  </BrowserRouter>
```